# Have to find the best possible combination

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to create a problem.

I have two grades of tiles

1. Medium Grade tiles at 180 cash each.
2. Low Grade tiles at 150 cash each.

I have with me 28000 in cash and I have to buy at least 160 tiles.

I have to find a combination where I will have to buy the least number of low grade tiles.

What branch of mathematics deals with this? Combinations?

Comment: Note that $160\times180=28800<280000$, so there's no need to buy low grade tiles.

Comment: It's a linear programming problem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

It is Linear Programming Problem.

See attached to find the solution using EXCEL SOLVER. Answer is 27 of L grade tiles.

Optimization problem Construction

Min L

With following constraints.

180*M + 150*L <=28000

M+L >= 160

[image]